# Where is source code for a Linux/Unix application most appropriately kept?

Tags: linux, system-administration

As a developer, I've often downloaded and run

```
./configure
./make
./make install
```

to install apps onto my Linux system. But I've never been quite clear on the best place to keep the downloaded directory. My local `Desktop` is the default location, but I'd like to know what the best "official" place to keep it is.  Also, does it vary by distro?

I'm running Ubuntu for now. I know apt-get install can do this for you, but sometimes the app I'm interested in simply isn't available on those lists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps "/usr/local/src" ? ;-)

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at the [FileSystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-4.9.html): it's `/usr/local/src`. However, this is a contentious issue as you will find [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/introduction/position.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I've never been clear on just where to put these, and that helps to put things in perspective.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a package manager, allow it to use the default for managed packages. If you administer the box, put unmanaged third party tools under `/usr/local` as [Steel Plume suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741888/where-is-source-code-for-a-linux-unix-application-kept/741891#741891) (though there are some who prefer `/opt`). If installing as a unprivileged user, unpack and compile in `$(HOME)/src`, and install into `$(HOME)/bin`, `$(HOME)/etc`, and so on.

Comment: I asked this question a couple of years ago on some other forum when developing a Python app on a Linux box.  I knew about the standard linked to by dirkgently, but I went with /opt.  Nobody communicated to me that this was necessarily a bad idea.

Comment: I wouldn't call it bad. Just unusual. The best argument *for* /opt that I know, it that it can be mounted without first mounting /usr. This is a small but real bonus. However, /usr/local has a *long* history.

Answer (score 2):

for personal use: ~/src

for sharing across a system: /usr/local/src

Answer (score 0):

@dirkgently and @dmckee are completely spot on. I would add that since it is can be a contentious issue, I would mimic what the distribution provider (in your case) Ubuntu does for its major packages.